# NGINX Configuration :

Tags: nginx

I am new to NGINX and I am trying to load balance our ERP web servers. 
I have 3 webserver running on port 80 powered by websphere which are a black box to me:

```
* web01.example.com/path/apphtml
* web02.example.com/path/apphtml
* web03.example.com/path/apphtml
```

NGINX is listening for the virtual URL ourerp.example.com and proxying it to the cluster.

Here is my config:

```
upstream myCluster {
    ip_hash;
    server web01.example.com:80;
    server web02.example.com:80;
    server web03.example.com:80;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  ourerp.example.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$  /path/apphtml break;
        proxy_pass       http://myCluster;
    }
}
```

When I only use proxy_pass, then NGINX load balances but forwards the request to web01.example.com and not web01.example.com/path/apphtml

When I try adding url rewrite, it simply rewrite the virtual URL and i end up with  ourerp.example.com/path/apphtml.

Is it possible to do URL rewrite at the upstream level or append the path to the app at the upstream level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to map `/` to `/path/apphtml/` through the proxy, use:

```
proxy_pass http://myCluster/path/apphtml/;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

The problem with your `rewrite` statement is a missing a `$1` on the end of the replacement string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more, but as I indicated above, you do not need the `rewrite` statement, as the `proxy_pass` statement is capable of doing the same job anyway.

Comment: Richard, thanks for your response. I did try and map through proxy as you mentioned but then NGINX request sent back to the browser is the virtual URL with path added, it does not use one of the server in the cluster

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. After more trouble shooting I found out my issue was that I was not using the load balancer URL correctly. Once I used ourerp.example.com/path/apphtml/ instead of ourerp.example.com, I was load balancing.